# Write binary data using XMLStreamWriterEx( stax-ex-api)

Tags: java, xml, binary, stax

The documentation says that XMLStreamWriter should be downcast to XMLStreamWriterEx to implement.But it throws ClassCastException.There is no example of how one should implement it.

I tried doing the following and as expected ,ClassCastException was thrown.

```
XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(outFile);
XMLStreamWriterEx xmlStreamWriterEx = (XMLStreamWriterEx) xmlStreamWriter;

if(xmlStreamWriter instanceof XMLStreamWriterEx){
    System.out.println("Voila!");
}
```

Is there any other way or API that i can use to write binary data using xmlstreamwriter?

Comment: Looks like Java code. Can you add a proper language tag too?

Comment: Which documentation says this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the XMLStreamWriterEx is an interface which extends the XMLStreamWriter, trying to cast to this interface would result in undefined methods.  You need to cast to a concrete class that implements the XMLStreamWriterEx.